# How do you test multiple Sign in with Apple users?

Tags: iphone, testing, sign-in-with-apple

I know I can create sandbox apple accounts, that's not what I'm asking, basically I'm asking what's the best way to actually test those different apple accounts in my app?

Ideally id like to be able to run two simulator both logged in to two different apple accounts and make sure the app is coordinating/updating between the two accounts and behaving how I intend. But as far I know you can't use "Sign in with Apple" on a simulator. It just hangs on the Sign in, I haven't gotten it to work and haven't found any solutions yet.

Would my only option be to have multiple iPones to run it on? Also, is there a better way to test a sandbox user than to logout of my account and sign into different sandbox accounts every time I try to test it? Because that's become a pain in the ass.

Thanks in advance.